# How can I test my react router?

Tags: javascript, testing, react-router

I built a simple `MyRouter` component based on [`react-router`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/). Now I'd like to test my routing logic, like this:

```
it('should show AboutPage for /about`, () => {
    let vdom = renderMyRouterForPath('/about');
    expect(vdom).toEqual(<AboutPage />);
}
```

I'm using plain Jasmine in Node, no Jest mocking magic. It would be also nice to avoid rendering the whole thing in DOM (virtual DOM should be enough, I don't mean to test DOM interactions).

I've had some success with setting `history={ history.createMemoryHistory(path) }` in [`Router`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#router), but this wasn't enough. I tried [shallow rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html#shallow-rendering), but with no luck (it returns the `Router` build by `MyRouter`).

How can I implement the `renderMyRouterForPath` function?